# Google Maps v3 tileloaded Event

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dom-events

I've been trying to create a "Loading Images" message while the tiles of the Google Map are being loaded. My implementation basically goes like this:

- When the **maptypeid_changed** or **idle** events fire, I display the loading message
- The loading message is removed as soon as the **tilesloaded** event fires

The problems I'm facing are:

- When the tiles for a map are already loaded (say in the cache or from a previous panning operation), the **tilesloaded** event isn't fired.
- If the tiles for a map view aren't completely loaded and I change the map type, the **tilesloaded** event fires twice. I've put a workaround by setting a flag to see if a map type change is followed by a **tilesloaded** event, and if not, the code discards the first **tilesloaded** event it receives after receiving a **maptypeid_changed** event.

Since there is no **aretilesloaded** function, is there anyway I can check if the tiles are already loaded before displaying the loading message. Also, is there anyway around the double firing of the **tilesloaded** event or will I have to use the discarding approach?

Answer (score 0):

What I have done in the past is that I set the "Loading" message as the background image for the map div using CSS. This way the image always show when there are no titles on top, meaning that they are being loaded.

You can take a look at how it work at http://geobetty.com/el-paso-tx/trail-map

I have the image being centered. If you want to the loading message show everywhere where there is no title then just set your css background rule to repeat;